# Insert file with name containing yesterday's Date using BCP

Tags: sql-server, windows, batch-file, command-line, bcp

I have a BCP command which has a hard coded file name `ID_Customer_160216.csv`. The file name ends in a date with formatted as `yymmdd`

```
bcp sfnav.dbo.Customer in "C:\Users\TSL\Desktop\TSL Data\ID_Customer_151124.csv" -F2 -c -t "^" -r "\n" -S ftpserver\sqlexpress -U abc -P xyz
```

I want to make it dynamic: replace it with yesterday's date in the given format.

Comment: Where are you running this command from... command line in Windows, or from SQL Server by executing the command with stored procedure `xp_cmdshell`?

Comment: from command line in Windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boot up Powershell ISE and paste the following in.  I think this is kinda what you are after....?  I know its not cmd but, it is time to move on from that sort of thing anyway ;)

```
$yesterdaysDateExtension = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).ToString("yyMMdd")
$fileName = "ID_Customer_$yesterdaysDateExtension.csv"

$filePath = "C:\Users\TSL\Desktop\TSL Data\$fileName"

Write-Host "Attempting bcp with file $filePath"
bcp sfnav.dbo.Customer in $filePath -F2 -c -t "^" -r "\n" -S ftpserver\sqlexpress -U abc -P xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

A robust way  :

**RunBCP.bat**

```
@echo off

::Creating the VBS code that give yesterday date
echo wscript.echo DateAdd("d", -1, date(^)^)>Day.vbs

::Getting yesterday date with day.vbs
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=/" %%a in ('cscript //nologo Day.vbs') do set "$date=%%c%%b%%a"
del Day.vbs 2>nul

::setting date to YYMMDD
set "$Date=%$Date:~2%"

::Running BCP with the substitued Date
bcp sfnav.dbo.Customer in "C:\Users\TSL\Desktop\TSL Data\ID_Customer_%$Date%.csv" -F2 -c -t "^" -r "\n" -S ftpserver\sqlexpress -U abc -P xyz
```

You just have to then run ***RunBCP.bat***